# Computer unusable after Windows 10 Update 1803

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I was prompted to update windows 10 to the latest version last night (don't remember which build), and I was greeted to an unsuable computer this morning when I tried logging in.

After logging in, my desktop was black and only showed the recycle bin icon.
I got an error on the screen that said "windows 10 c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\desktop is unavailable" 
I can't open the start menu or the control panel, settings, etc. My wireless driver and sound driver do not work. I tried to troubleshoot the sound driver and it fixed the problem, but the wireless driver doesn't work.

I am currently connected to the web via Ethernet, and it works.

I found that the only way I can open an application is to open the task manager, and Run a New Task, and then browse for the browser executable.

I can't even manage to restart in safe mode.

For the record, I'm running a 5 yr old HP DV7 laptop, i7 Quad, 12gb ram, and my os is on an SSD.

Also, Windows is on my C: drive, and all my users files (desktop, my documents, etc.) are on my D: drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would enable the buil-in Administrator to see if once enabled it will let you revert back to the versjon of Windows you were using before

Comment: @Ramhound Not quite sure how I would do that. I tried booting Windows into recovery mode and safe mode, but it just not into the regular Windows. Also, in the past whenever I tried to roll back to a previous version, I would get an error.

Comment: You can enable the built-in Administrator from a command prompt within WinRE.  I can confirm Windows does not (nor has it ever) liked it when you move your user profile directory to another disk

Comment: 1803 has known issues with some SSD drives, may or may not be your problem....https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&ei=mTUHW-bBJsjYtQWstJXIBw&q=windows+10+1803+ssd+problem&oq=windows+10+1803+ssd+problem&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.149985.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.fqSG2afiMig

Comment: @Ramhound I enabled the admin account and tried logging in. Its loading and says: "Preparing Windows". An error popped up: "sihost.exe - System Warning" "Unknown Hard Error". After moments later I got another error: "explorer.exe -System Warning" "Unknown Hard Error".

Comment: @Ramhound the admin account finally loaded, but I am still not able to access the start menu or control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to download the **[Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)**
And do an upgrade install of 1803.

Make sure keep apps and settings are checked

The only time I see this happen is when someone interrupts sysprep, especially by turning the computer off(or losing power) in the middle of an upgrade.

Comment: I tried downloading the Media Creation Tool, but it crashed multiple times while downloading the files. I downloaded the 1803 update directly from Microsoft's website, and "burned" it to a flash drive, and then while the computer was running I opened the executable. The installation seemed to have completed, but I now have the same problem as before. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried booting from the USB drive and rolling beack to the previous version of Windows, but it  did not do anything. Am I doomed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being caused by a conflict between Avast antivirus program and the Windows 10 1803 Update, where the update was not properly installed due to Avast restricting access to some parts of the computer. This problem is well documented on Reddit if you Google it.

I found multiple fixes online, such as:
1. Restart in safe mode, and download and run the Avast Uninstaller, which is found on the Avast website.
2. Create a Windows 10 media CD or bootable USB drive.
3. Login to a Windows administrator account, and launch the windows 10 installer from the media you created. Since I didn't have access to "My Computer" or any settings menu, I simply launched the task manager, clicked "start new task", and browsed for the windows setup file and executed it as an admin. Once the installer loads, select the option to update Windows.

This process worked for many, but didn't work for me. It looked like windows was installing, but after restarting the computer, I was back at my original problem.

So I resorted to reinstalling Windows 10 1803 fresh, and it installed correctly while placing my old windows files in a windows.old folder.
Since I kept my old user files on a separate hard drive, I was able to simply remap the folders back to where they should be, and everything is fine. All I need to do is reinstall my programs.

Hope this helps!